# eclipse cdt - change type of project

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a bunch of Eclipse projects imported into my workspace. 
I know how to add a directory for Eclipse to search for headers to resolve symbols.

However, some of my projects do not allow me to add these directories and I realized that it's because those projects are not the correct type.

**Right click > Properties** on the 'correct' type of project shows an item in the list called "**C/C++ Build**

If it has this entry, then in **C/C++ General** it has an entry called **Paths and Symbols** wherein I can add necessary include directories so that the indexing works.

**QUESTION**

How do I change the properties of this project so I can use indexing and add directories for indexing?

I've found one thing that obviously needs to be changed: in the 'correct' project, **Right Click > Properties > Builders** has two entries: **CDT Builder** and **Scanner Configuration Builder** while the 'incorrect' project is missing these two.

How do I add them? 
**Import** yields a blank page and **New** is just as useless.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `File -> New -> Convert to a C/C++ Project (Adds C/C++ Nature)`.